# How to stop Timer Using JavaScript after a predefined time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timer

I am working on a web based application i.e `LMS Learning Management System`. In this application a student can read chapters and give test for that chapters. And for reading a chapter a specific time is alotted to the user which is `capturing using the timer tick`. While reading the chapter, a `captcha`(i.e developed in aspx page) comes at after every `12 minutes`. Now i want when captcha comes on the window while reading, the `timer should get paused`, and when user submit the captcha timer get `resumed` from where it left its previous tick. For this i have tried a solution using javascript but it didn't work.

Here is the codr that i have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        function startTimer() {
            var timer = $find("<%=Timer1.ClientID%>")
            timer._startTimer();
        }

        function stopTimer() {
            var timer = $find("<%=Timer1.ClientID%>")
            timer._stopTimer();
        }

        function showCaptchaOnChapter() {
            //stopTimer();
            ShowNewPage();

            setTimeout('showCaptchaOnChapter()', 120000);
            stopTimer();
        }
        function showRandomQuestionOnChapter() {
            ShowChapterQuestion();
            setTimeout('showRandomQuestionOnChapter()', 900000);
        }
        //setTimeout('showCaptchaOnChapter()', 360000);
        //setTimeout('showRandomQuestionOnChapter()', 120000);
    </script>
```

The definition for `ShowNewPage()`

```
function ShowNewPage() {
    var callbackFunctionArray = new Array(CloseCaptchaPopUp);
    modalWin.ShowURL('Captcha.aspx', 225, 290, 'Please enter characters dislayed in image to proceed', null, callbackFunctionArray);

}
```

here in this script i had set Captcha arrival time at 2 minutes so i can test faster. Captcha coming at Regular interval i.e of 2 minutes but timer tick not getting stopped.
How could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

After the time out has occurred show your captcha and initiate other timeout.

```
function showQuestion() {
    updateTimer();
    getQuestion();
    setTimeout(showCaptcha, time);
}

function showCaptcha() {
   getCaptcha();
   //some listener for submitting of captcha eg:submitCaptcha
}

function submitCaptcha() {
    if captcha===correct
         showQuestion();
}
```

Comment: showQuestion(); function isn't required. I need that the timer get paused when captcha comes on screen.